# Don't let eval access variables in function

Tags: javascript, for-loop, eval

I made a JSFiddle for my problem: (Also below)
https://jsfiddle.net/oymrrL81/

```
var code = ["alert('first');n=1;", "alert('second');", "alert('third');IWantThisVariableChanged = true;", "alert('fourth');"];

var IWantThisVariableChanged = false;

function doStuff(){
  for(var n = 0; n != 4;n++){
    eval(code[n]);
  }
}

doStuff();

alert("Variable changed? " + IWantThisVariableChanged);
```

Basically I would like code evaluated inside a function, to only be able to access variables outside of the function the eval is in. This is because it changes my variable I use for my for-loop, ruining the loop. And please don't recommend I change my variable name in my loop :(, I need a solution to any variable name.

Comment: ez, never, EVER, use eval.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? If you don't want the local `n` to be modified, which `n` **do** you want to be modified?

Comment: darn downvoters

Answer (score 1):

Try executing the `eval` in a different context. like

```
function inContext(code){
    eval(code);
}

function doStuff(){
  for(var n = 0; n != 4;n++){
    inContext.call(null, code[n]);
    //eval(code[n]);
  }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: @torazaburo `context` variable was something i was fiddling in jsfiddle, removed that part. The difference is that in the original code, when `eval` was called in `doStuff` it was executing in that local scope and interfering with the `n` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object to store values, `Object.keys()`, `RegExp.prototype.test`, `Strin.prototype.split()`, `String.prototype.replace()`, `isNaN`, `Number`, `Boolean`, `new Function` constructor

```js
var code = ["alert('first');n=1;"
           , "alert('second');"
           , "alert('third');IWantThisVariableChanged = true;"
           , "alert('fourth');"];

var obj = {
  IWantThisVariableChanged: false,
  n: null
};

function doStuff(o) {
  let props = Object.keys(o);
  for (let n = 0; n != 4; n++) {
    for (var i = 0, prop = void 0; i < props.length; i++) {
      if (new RegExp(props[i] + "(?=\\s+=|=)").test(code[n])) {
        prop = props[i];
        break;
      }
    };
    if (prop) {
      var value = code[n].split(prop).pop().replace(/=|;/g, "");
      o[prop] = !isNaN(value) ? Number(value) : Boolean(value);
    }
    new Function(code[n])();
  }
}

doStuff(obj);

alert("Variable changed? " + obj.IWantThisVariableChanged);
console.log(obj);
```